# SSH connection issue only by bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

The bash script try connect a remote host through:

```
CNX=$(bash -c 'exec 3<> /dev/tcp/'$OPCION'/'22';echo $?' 2>/dev/null)
   if [ "$CNX" = "1" ]; then
     telnet "$OPCION"
   else
      ssh -vvv "$OPCION"
fi
```

But it finish with this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

[myuser@vmlnx01 .escrip]$ ./menu

Usar CRTL + C para salir.
Patron a buscar:
remot
1) RemoteRouter
#? 1
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 57: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to RemoteRouter [1.1.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Connection to remote host without script is successful:

```
^C[myuser@vmlnx01 .escrip]$ ssh RemoteRouter
------------------
ACCESO RESTRINGIDO
------------------
myuser@RemoteRouter's password:
```

The remote host is a router and it shows this logs:

```
RP/0/RSP1/CPU0:Apr  5 03:55:46.210 : SSHD_[65590]: %SECURITY-SSHD-6-INFO_GENERAL : Client 10.108.120.4 closes socket connection
RP/0/RSP1/CPU0:Apr  5 03:55:46.211 : SSHD_[65590]: %SECURITY-SSHD-3-ERR_GENERAL : Failed in version exchange
```

Comment: Quite a mess of a post but one thing you should do in a script is quote the shell variable reference: `telnet "$OPCION"` and `ssh -vvv "$OPCION"`.

Comment: Sorry by the mess. I tried your suggestion but the issue continues.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was the issue, but it is certainly a necessary change for future reference. I edited to reformat for readability. I was looking at the original on my phone, which exacerbated the clutter a bit.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the mess

Comment: Does the command inside of the `$( )` work by itself on the command line, (without using any variables)? If NO, then you need to fix that first, then add variables, then enclose in `CNX=$(...)`. Good luck.

Comment: Also, including `2>/dev/null` may be discarding important debug information. The output from std-err (`2>`), will never be included in your assignment to CNX, so, I would leave that out. You should always want to see error messages when they appear. Good luck.

Comment: AND finally, what sort of value is set for `$OPCION` ? An I.P. address? OR ???? ;-) ? Please update your Q with that info, rather than reply in comments. Good luck.